# Typical reimbursement for unused vacation when paid semi-monthly

Tags: quitting, vacation, compensation

Typically, paid time off is granted in units of days. Also typically, upon ending ones employment, the employer pays the employee the value of his/her unused vacation days. If the payroll schedule is twice a month, how is the value of a day calculated since different months have different numbers of work days?

Comment: Are you sure it has any value.  In my state if the employment contact does not have a cash equivalent of a vacation day the value is $0.  I had a company go under and got $0 for my unused vacation days.  Your best bet is to take vacation days and then quit.

Comment: @blam it might not have any legal value, but I believe it is typical for employers to compensate for unused vacation days. At least my company does that.

Comment: Voting to close because [Questions seeking advice on company-specific regulations, agreements, or policies](http://meta.workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/2693/custom-off-topic-close-reasons-change/2694#2694) are off-topic.

Comment: Take on board about how company specific this is,  removed answer and voted to close.

Comment: @davidk I'm not asking about company-specific policies. I'm asking what's done typically.

Comment: @Daniel As HLGEM's answer points out, unfortunately there is no typical. The best way to get the answer you are looking for is to look at your employee handbook.

Comment: @Daniel  To follow up on David's comment, typical may also vary country by country, region by region.  I know in my home province in Canada they are determined based on a government supplied formula so there is zero ambiguity.

Answer (score 7):

Not every company calculates this the same way. Not every company pays out unused vacation. This is question for your local HR or you can look in your employee handbook which should describe the policy.